# Getting filenames from azure storage given url folder path

Tags: c#, azure

For starters, yes I know there are no "real" folders in Azure storage, but given a url path to an image of

> https://myazurestorage.blob.core.windows.net/accessibleimages/folder/folder/myimage.JPG

Is there a method to generate the list of filenames by passing in the base url of

> https://myazurestorage.blob.core.windows.net/accessibleimages/folder/folder/

I can't seem to find any reference to one. I can get a list of blobs, but they are the base "folders" in the containers but I need to drill deeper to get the specific filenames.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how you can do this:
1. Create blob client:

```
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("myazurestorage", YOUR_API_KEY), true);
var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
```

2. Get container:

```
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("acessibleimages");
```

3. Use ListBlobs like this (read more about [flat blob listing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/JJ732032.aspx)):

```
var blobList= container.ListBlobs(prefix: "folder/folder", useFlatBlobListing: true);
```

4. After you have your list of blobs you can iterate through them and extract path like this: `foreach (var blob in blobs){blob.StorageUri.PrimaryUri;}`

Answer (score 0):

RAS's answer is correct but I have a solution with only two steps.
Since, according to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.listblobs?view=azure-dotnet), there is also a ListBlobs function in the CloudBlobClient class, we can get the blobs without creating the container object. the following are the steps:

1. Create blob client:

```
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("myazurestorage", YOUR_API_KEY), true);
var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
```

2. Use ListBlobs like this:

```
var blobList= container.ListBlobs(prefix: "folder/folder/", useFlatBlobListing: true);
```

Be noticed of the ending **forward slash(/)**. if not added, the function returns the folder per se. if added, returns the blobs in the folder.

And unlike web development, if the prefix starts with "/", it will not work and return 404 (cannot find page.)

Also Azure Storage is case sensitive.

Use **useFlatBlobListing**, according to what you want. Why microsoft just use the word recursive? I think **recursive** is better.